# XML content management

Tags: html, .net, xml, content-management-system

Hi there everyone this is my first time posting here, I am a student working for a really small company and I am in charge of developing the company's website.
Since I am only here for two more months, the boss wants to be able to change some content of the website without having to do any code.

He mentioned the idea of having an XML file he can update online, that will update the content of parts of the website. He does not want anything to do with third party websites.

So I was just wondering if this is even possible, I have no experience with XML, and really have no idea of where to start. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is basically what the CMS does (like WordPress.org)! But there is even no nedd of any XML file. (No need for third party website for wordpress.ORG contrary to WordPress.com)

Comment: Does he plan on this XML containing HTML or just text that will be inserted into an HTML structure?

Comment: He's willing to update XML, but not HTML? They're practically the same thing (except HTML is much more forgiving of mistakes).

Comment: I think you should have a look at some working cms like joomla, drupal, wordpress. All in all there are so many content management systems that a choice is difficult, but starting from the scratch is overhead..

Answer (score 0):

Try a [server-side include (SSI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) with the something like the following tag:

```
<!--#include virtual="sitecontents/content_name_1.txt" -->
```

You can update the individual files (they don't necessarily have to include HTML tags) instead of trying to process an XML document. Much less development time and, frankly, much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this for my website but used a database-driven concept. I have a secure area where I can enter in data via forms into the various database tables and then the information is automatically updated on the site via PHP.  Takes awhile to get it all in place and working but has been worth the effort.

Now that I'm think about it, you can do this with XML as well.  I played around with it a bit before developing the database-driven site.  If you're not familiar with XML though it might be a stretch to get it done in the short time you have.  You will also need to know XSLT which can be confusing at times.  It is needed to connect to the XML file (data source) and then to parse the data and transform the information into something that looks good.